# How can I download options data from yahoo using Perl?

Tags: perl, finance, trading

I am trying to get yahoo options data into mysql using perl.  I found modules to download stock prices, but not options data.  Anyone know what would be the easiest way to do that?  If I have to roll my own, what modules should I use?
Thanks,
CP

Comment: How much data are you looking for? The OPRA tape is big. Are you operating a strategy doing something like looking for imbalances between  the stock and the volatility or are you trading a basket?

Comment: I am looking for just end of day options prices, so I can do various analysis on them.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any specific modules for Yahoo! Finance options, but if you want to roll your own you can usw [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.836/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) to download the page in question and something like [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~petek/HTML-Tree-3.23/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm) to parse it. If a specific option is the one you need data for, Yahoo! may even offer an RSS feed of its data in which case it's probably more robust to use something like [XML::RSS](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-RSS-1.48/lib/XML/RSS.pm) to parse the feed.

Do you have a link to a page of the kind of data you'd like to get?

Comment: No they don't have a rss feed for options, but here is an example link: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=IBM+Options

I saw Template::Extract and the idea sounds great, but I am unable to get it to work correctly.

Comment: It doesn't appear they have any feeds anywhere, then. But if you go to the options page and follow every option listed (example: http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=IBM100619C00125000), you can get to a page with CSV data (http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=IBM100619C00125000&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv) where you can download the data for an option for a given strike price. CSV is trivially easy to parse in Perl (just a loop and a call to split), so that might be enough.

Comment: Don't use `split` to parse CSVs, you never know when you'll run into quoted values with embedded commas, and other gotchas. Test::CSV_XS http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS/CSV_XS.pm is much better.

Comment: Well sure the caveat about quoted values with commas applies. I'm sure a sufficiently ugly regex could deal with it. But it's important to get something up and running and then iterate on it. CptanPanic can probably get something decent running with just LWP::UserAgent and regexes, and then add robustness to flavor :-D.

Comment: Ok I go the route where I follow each link to download the csv file, what would be the easiest way to get all the links on the main page that point to each option listed?  For example get all the links that look like <a href="/q?s=IBM100619C00100000">IBM100619C00100000</a>

Answer (score 1):

The [Finance::Quote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Finance::Quote) module implements the lookup on Yahoo and a number of other sources.

Comment: This only does stock quotes, and not options quotes.